# How to install gu native-image for native Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I am following this official [tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image) for native Quarkus but can't run the following step:

```sh
# 3. Install the native-image tool using gu install:
${GRAALVM_HOME}/bin/gu install native-image
```

The `${GRAALVM_HOME}/bin` directory does not exist in the GraalVM distribution.

I downloaded the latest GraalVM from https://github.com/oracle/graal/releases, version 19.3.1 at this date.

How should I run the `${GRAALVM_HOME}/bin/gu install native-image` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the wrong GraalVM release.

The releases have moved to https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases.